# How do I validate data in Automator?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, automator

I'm making an app in Automator to quickly delete my iMovie Library (to save space). However, I want my app to check if the iMovie Library has already been deleted and show a dialog saying so. I know how to make the dialog, but I can't figure out how to do it. How do I do this? I'm using macOS 10.11.

My workflow:

1. Ask for confirmation
2. Get specified Finder items (the validation would go after this)
3. Move Finder items to trash
4. Run AppleScript (to show a dialog saying "Done")

Comment: Show us the workflow and code you already have. Also what version of OS X/macOS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Run AppleScript action to perform validation. Between actions 2 and 3 in your workflow, add a Run AppleScript action with the following:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    if input is {} then
        display notification "File already deleted"
        tell me to quit
    end if
    return input
end run
```

This checks if the input is empty (because the file can't be found), and if so, runs your desired code — you can customise `display notification` as you please, such as showing an alert. The use of `tell me to quit` if the input is empty will stop the workflow at this point.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but a bit more info could be added.

You can use other "Run" actions Automator, not just AppleScript. You can **Run a Shell Script** as well. An exit value of the script that is 0 will be deemed a successful check, any other value will be an error. And the equivalent to "Display notification" is the stderr from the script. So:

1. **Ask for Text** - creates a single-variable dialog
2. **Set Value of Variable** - gives the collected variable a name
3. **Run Shell Script** - pass input to [stdin]

   ```
    read -r varname
    if [[ ! "$varname" =~ ^SomeValidatingRegexp$ ]]; then
      echo "Validation failed!" >&2
      exit 1
    fi
   ```
4. **Ask for Text** - next variable
5. etc.